How to Determine the Coefficient of MA and Use Two Sides of Numf in Yulewalk Filter Design?
This is how the coefficient of MA is determined, and why two sides of numf are used?
function [B, A] = yulewalk2(na, ff, aa)
% YULEWALK Recursive filter design using a least-squares method.
%   [B, A] = YULEWALK(N, F, M) finds the N-th order recursive filter
%   coefficients B and A such that the filter:
% 
%          B(z)   b(1) + b(2)z^(-1) + ... + b(N)z^(-(N-1))
%          ---- = ---------------------------------------
%          A(z)    1   + a(1)z^(-1) + ... + a(N)z^(-(N-1))
%
%   matches the magnitude frequency response given by vectors F and M.

npt = 512 + 1; % Number of points

Ht = zeros(1, npt);
Ht(1:end-1) = interp1(ff, aa, linspace(0, 1, npt-1), 'linear'); % Interpolated magnitude response
Ht = [Ht Ht(npt-1:-1:2)]; % Symmetrize the response

n = length(Ht);
n2 = fix((n + 1) / 2);
nr = 4 * na;
nt = 0:1:nr-1;

% Compute correlation function of magnitude squared response
R = real(ifft(Ht .* Ht));
R = R(1:nr) .* (0.54 + 0.46 * cos(pi * nt / (nr - 1)));

% Form window to be used in extracting the right "wing" of two-sided covariance sequence.
Rwindow = [1/2 ones(1, n2-1) zeros(1, n-n2)]; 

A = polystab(denf(R, na)); % Compute denominator

Qh = numf([R(1)/2, R(2:nr)], A, na); % Compute additive decomposition

Ss = 2 * real(freqz(Qh, A, n, 'whole'))'; % Compute impulse response
hh = ifft(exp(fft(Rwindow .* ifft(log(Ss)))));
B = real(numf(hh(1:nr), A, na));

function b = numf(h, a, nb)
%NUMF   Find numerator B given impulse-response h of B/A and denominator A
%   NB is the numerator order.  This function is used by YULEWALK.

nh = max(size(h)); 
impr = filter(1, a, [1 zeros(1, nh-1)]);
b = h/toeplitz(impr, [1 zeros(1, nb)])';

function A = denf(R, na)
%DENF   Compute denominator from covariances.
%   A = DENF(R, NA) computes order NA denominator A from covariances 
%   R(0)...R(nr) using the Modified Yule-Walker method.  
%   This function is used by YULEWALK.

nr = max(size(R));
Rm = toeplitz(R(na+1:nr-1), R(na+1:-1:2));
Rhs = -R(na+2:nr);
A = [1 Rhs/Rm'];

I wish you could tell me the formula for deriving the MA coefficient, I can't understand it, although I can roughly understand the formula. I can't understand the numerical tricks of the code
